# screen resolution to be improved from the existing maximum

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, resolution

I just reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate on my laptop and the screen resolution is maxed out at 1024x768. It is usable but the characters are noticeably less clear than on the former installation. The pictures are seen wider, not as original.

What should I do to get a large resolution scale on the same system?

Comment: What is the native resolution of the laptop screen?

My own laptop didn't have graphics drivers compatible with Windows 7, yet it was able to display full native resolution without issue. Playing some HD videos or 3D acceleration was out of the question as was Aero, but resolution was native and not really an issue otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

It sounds like you have the wrong video drivers installed. 1024x768 is a resolution the base windows VGA driver sets.

Right click on your desktop and select Screen Resolution. Does it offer higher settings?

If not, do you know who made the video card in your laptop? Go get the latest drivers available for it. You will find them here for the "Big Three" graphics chip makers:

- http://www.nvidia.com (NVidia)
- http://www.amd.com (AMD/ATI)
- http://www.intel.com (Intel)

If it's the actual display hardware (either the card or the actual LCD display) causing that low resolution, there is nothing you can do as laptops are pretty inflexible when it comes to upgrades. Hopefully it's just a driver issue.

Comment: Yup, probably just need proper drivers. Normally running the optional updates on Windows Update will find the correct graphics card drivers too, if you dont want to, or dont know how to, go hunting around for them manually.